# How to add a MovieClip instance to multiple movie clips and iterate over the children of a MovieClip parent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
var mainmc:MovieClip;
var mc1:MovieClip;
var mc2:MovieClip;
var mc3:MovieClip;
var lastmc:MovieClip;

mainmc.addChild(mc1);
mainmc.addChild(mc2);
mainmc.addChild(mc3);

mc1.addChild(lastmc);
mc2.addChild(lastmc);
mc3.addChild(lastmc);

for(var i=1; i<4; i++){ 
  mainmc.?????.lastmc.visible=false;
}
```

What do I need to write on the ground with the question marks?

Comment: Try to explain what you're trying to do so someone can better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. You can't add same MovieClip `lastmc` to several parents at once. From your code, `lastmc` will be only in `mc3`

If you want to iterate over children of `mainmc`:

```
var i: uint, len: uint = mainmc.numChildren, movie:MovieClip;

for(i; i < len; ++i){
    movie = mainmc.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
    if(movie != null && movie.numChildren > 0){
        movie.getChildAt(0).visible = false;
    }
}
```